# Wider to longer format but with some additional steps

Tags: r, dplyr

I get the following dataframe when I import data,

```
Input <-  structure(list(...1 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Segment", "Small", "Small"
), ...2 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Business Product", "CA", 
            "CA"), 
...3 = c("Fiscal Year", "Period", "Account", 
                                          "Entity", "INDIA", "CHINA"), 
`Actuals in USD...4` = c("2022", "Nov", "Liabilities", "* 1,000", "100", "200"), 
`Actuals in USD...5` = c("2022","Dec", "Liabilities", "* 1,000", "400", "300"), 
`Actuals in USD...6` = c("2023","Jan", "Liabilities", "* 1,000", "100", "200")), 
class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

But I want to get it into a long format.  I have tried,unsuccesfuly, to use pivot_longer from tidyverse. Can someone please point in the right way to get the below output?

```
Output <- data.frame(Segment = c("Small","Small","Small","Small","Small","Small"),
                     `Business Product` = c("CA","CA","CA","CA","CA","CA"),
                     Entity = c("India","China","India","China","India","China"),
                     `Fiscal Year` = c(2022,2022,2022,2022,2023,2023),
                     Period = c("Nov","Nov","Dec","Dec","Jan","Jan"),
                     Liabilities = c(100,200,400,300,100,200))
```

Comment: You might wanna restructure your data before importing it to R.

Comment: @Maël I receive the file from upstream and there is just too many of these files for me to manually intervene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibly approach to clean your data which as a first step collapses the first four rows into one which could then be used as column names. Afterwards we could use `pivot_longer` and `separate` to transform your data into tidy format:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create column names: Collapse first four rows
col_names <- Input[1:4, ] |> 
  t() |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  unite("col_name", sep = "_", na.rm = TRUE) |> 
  pull(col_name)

Input |> 
  slice(-c(1:4)) |> 
  set_names(col_names) |> 
  rename(Entity = 3) |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(1:3), values_to = "Liabilities") |> 
  separate(name, c("Fiscal Year", "Period", "drop"), sep = "_") |> 
  select(-drop)
#> Warning: Expected 3 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 6 rows [1, 2, 3, 4,
#> 5, 6].
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>   Segment `Business Product` Entity `Fiscal Year` Period Liabilities
#>   <chr>   <chr>              <chr>  <chr>         <chr>  <chr>      
#> 1 Small   CA                 INDIA  2022          Nov    100        
#> 2 Small   CA                 INDIA  2022          Dec    400        
#> 3 Small   CA                 INDIA  2023          Jan    100        
#> 4 Small   CA                 CHINA  2022          Nov    200        
#> 5 Small   CA                 CHINA  2022          Dec    300        
#> 6 Small   CA                 CHINA  2023          Jan    200
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. It works for perfectly. Is there a way to pick values_to and cols in seperate from the initial dataset iteslf instead of typing it?